Error installing chaincode (java) in HyperledgerFabric usinng Bevel 1.1 helm chart
I am deploying a Fabric 2.5.4 network using Hyperledger Bevel v1.1 (not through Ansible and Flux but just using Helm charts thanks to this new feature in Bevel 1.1)
All process is solved but untill I execute the fabric-chaincode-install helm chart. The code is pulled from the repository and built OK (logs shows built ok)... but after that it is not installed in the corresponding peer:
2024-08-02 11:03:36.178 UTC 0001 DEBU [bccsp] GetDefault -> Before using BCCSP, please call InitFactories(). Falling back to bootBCCSP.
2024-08-02 11:03:36.182 UTC 0002 DEBU [bccsp] GetDefault -> Before using BCCSP, please call InitFactories(). Falling back to bootBCCSP.
2024-08-02 11:03:36.187 UTC 0003 DEBU [bccsp] GetDefault -> Before using BCCSP, please call InitFactories(). Falling back to bootBCCSP.
2024-08-02 11:03:36.190 UTC 0004 DEBU [bccsp_sw] openKeyStore -> KeyStore opened at [/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/crypto/admin/msp/keystore]...done
2024-08-02 11:03:36.190 UTC 0005 DEBU [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> Reading directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/crypto/admin/msp/signcerts
2024-08-02 11:03:36.190 UTC 0006 DEBU [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> Inspecting file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/crypto/admin/msp/signcerts/server.crt
2024-08-02 11:03:36.190 UTC 0007 WARN [msp] getPemMaterialFromDir -> Failed reading file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/crypto/admin/msp/signcerts/server.crt: no pem content for file /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/crypto/admin/msp/signcerts/server.crt
2024-08-02 11:03:36.190 UTC 0008 DEBU [msp] newBccspMsp -> Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2024-08-02 11:03:36.190 UTC 0009 DEBU [msp] New -> Creating Cache-MSP instance
2024-08-02 11:03:36.190 UTC 000a DEBU [msp] loadLocalMSP -> Created new local MSP
2024-08-02 11:03:36.190 UTC 000b ERRO [main] InitCmd -> Cannot run peer because error when setting up MSP of type bccsp from directory /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/crypto/admin/msp: Setup error: nil conf reference

I use DinD Docker in Docker to run internal java chaincode (I'm not using external chaincode) Any suggestions on how to diagnose this?
